# Why do prepared statements protect against injections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I've come os far as to gaining basic understanding of prepared statements and I get that they prevent SQL-injection attacks. But I have yet to understand WHY they protect against said attacks. I know there are similar questions asked but I didn't find the answers entirely satisfying.

Example - very unsafe code
So here we have the most basic way to communicate with our database:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users where id=$username";
```

Without any protection, a user can input malicious code and thus "trick" the database engine to execute a devastating query:

```
$username = "1; DROP TABLE users;"
SELECT * FROM users where id=1; DROP TABLE users;
```

What I don't understand is how a prepared statement manages to "filter out" such data. What is the mechanic behind it that does NOT lure the database to generate such a SQL-query as shown above? Is just as simple as escaping certain characters, like semicolon in the example above, or is it more complicated?

If I was to do the exact injection attack as in the example, but running it through a prepared statement, what kind of command string would reach the database engine?

Comment: In short: true prepared statements are integral to the database-server: there is _never_ a 'complete query', just the prepared statement, and after that you tell the database what variables you are going to use. This way, the intention of the query can never be misinterpreted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does PHP PDO's prepared statements prevent sql injection? What are other benefits of using PDO? Does using PDO reduce efficiency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718942/how-does-php-pdos-prepared-statements-prevent-sql-injection-what-are-other-ben)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do prepared statements in PDO really increase security?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946535/do-prepared-statements-in-pdo-really-increase-security)

Comment: The security benefit is merely a by-product. Prepared statements were intended for languages without string interpolation, yet primarily for optimizing execution plans. The security aspect only comes into play when you strictly stick to them. They just remove the tedious manual and error-prone escaping part. You still ought to learn about context, cause else you trip over it at some later date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statements don't just add in the text, they send it as data, and let the database process it separately. Because in reality the database doesn't actually use the SQL statements, it uses "compiled" versions of them.

Not quite sure I was clear, but it lies in how the query is sent to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are usually built to use parameter binding. It's really the parameter binding that insulates against these kinds of attacks. You can use parameter binding without using prepared statements.

The second level of protection that prepared statements offer is that each is a single statement (so the use of `;` to create two statements out of one won't work).

As a general rule, in order to be safe from injection attacks, the prepared statement must be prepared from data that is not derived from any external input.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you use standard untyped parameter binding, you will get

```
SELECT * FROM users where id='1; DROP TABLE users;'
```

Which will error out on the Database, but will do no harm.

Please understand, that this is not the sam thing as running

```
SELECT * FROM users where id='$username'
```

with a suitably escaped `$username` - it happens on a lower layer of your DB access stack.